# Visualforce does not process/validate fields on page

Tags: visualforce, validation, fields

I have an `apex:inputfield` of type date (on a custom object) on the page but when I click on it, the calendar does not show up. On another number field, when I type in 100k, it does not change to 100,000.

What am I missing here on my page?

```
<table>

<tr><td>Amount</td><td><apex:inputField value="{!bill.amount}"/></td></tr>

<tr><td>Date</td><td>

<div class="hideCurrDate" ><apex:inputField value="{!bill.billingdate__c}"/></div>
</td></tr>
</table>
<apex:commandbutton value="Book" action="{!updatebill}"/>
```

Comment: David ,Please share code so that people can assist  :)

Comment: There you go :)

Comment: Check for javascript errors on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have switched off salesforce style sheet ,then this will be affected and calendar will be hidden .

Check if page has StandardStylesheet=false at the apex:page attribute

Also inspect your class "hideCurrDate" to see if it something thats causing issues .

Answer (score 0):

as Mohith said if you are not using default styles you won't get javascript page event validations for free. You can display error messages on your page if the fields have validation rules and you wire your submit action to return the page with errors. I prefer to use my own javascript page event formatting validations before sending data to the server. There are great jQuery libs that can help you with this. 
Great article on the topic:
http://th3silverlining.com/2010/03/02/visualforce-form-validation-enhanced&/#8221

Answer (score 0):

Sample code to show date picker.
http://www.infallibletechie.com/2012/11/date-picker-in-visualforce-page.html

There are number of more examples if you search.